# Take an array of numbers, Then take out a randomly 25 numbers from that array in php

Tags: php, sql

Ok, so I am a bit lost here..

I am pulling profile IDs from an sql database into an array.

i would like to then take that array and randomly pick only 25 numbers each time the array loads, then shuffle up the numbers so there is less likely a chance they will show up in the same order.

Comment: Instead of fetching all of them and having to muck around in memory, you could do this in your query - `SELECT profile_id FROM my_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in MySQL directly:

```
SELECT id FROM profiles ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25
```

`RAND()` sorts randomly. This should be guarantee enough that *"there is less likely a chance they will show up in the same order"*. If you have more stringent demands on randomness, like uniqueness over draws you might need a more complex solution.

Comment: I did go with this one~

Answer (score 0):

```
shuffle($numbers);
```

then

```
array_pop  ($numbers)
```

Comment: Rather `shuffle()` and then `array_slice($numbers, 0, 25)`

Comment: right that works too I guess, i thought it would have been easier to use pop when in a loop since his probably displaying some kinds of html